# iphone push notification not work

Tags: php, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I am implementing a push notification in my application.

```
Server: php
Client: iphone
```

Sever side Coding:

```
function pushToIphone($deviceToken, $badge){
    ini_set('display_errors','on');
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    //$apnsHost = 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com';
    $apnsHost = 'gateway.push.apple.com';
    $apnsPort = 2195;
    $pem_path = dirname(__FILE__);  
    $pem_path = $pem_path .'\cert';
    $apnsCert = $pem_path.'\apns_cer.pem';

    echo $apnsCert."<br/>"; 
    $streamContext = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($streamContext, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $apnsCert);

    $apns = stream_socket_client('ssl://' . $apnsHost . ':' . $apnsPort, $error, $errorString, 2, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

    if($apns) {
        echo "Connection Established<br/>";

        $payload = array();
        //$payload['aps'] = array('alert' => 'BiiMe finds product for you', 'badge' => $badge, 'sound' => 'default');
        //$payload = get_payload_message('BiiMe finds product for you',$badge);
        //$payload['server'] = array('serverId' => $serverId, 'name' => $serverName);
        //$payload = json_encode($payload);

        $payload = get_payload_message('BiiMe finds product for you',$badge);
        $apnsMessage = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;

        echo $apnsMessage."<BR/>";

        $fwrite = fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);  
        echo $fwrite." bytes written<BR/>"; 
    } else {
        echo "Connection fail<br/>";
    }

    //socket_close($apns);  
    fclose($apns);
}

function get_payload_message($message_text,$badge,$sound='default')
{
    $PAYLOAD_MAXIMUM_SIZE = 256;

    $payload['aps'] = array("alert" => "$message_text", 'badge' => $badge, 'sound' => $sound);
    $payload = json_encode($payload);

    $nJSONPayloadLen = strlen($payload);
    if($nJSONPayloadLen > $PAYLOAD_MAXIMUM_SIZE)
    {
        $nTextLen = strlen($message_text);
        if($nJSONPayloadLen - $nTextLen <= $PAYLOAD_MAXIMUM_SIZE)
        {
            $badge_count = substr($message_text, 0, $nTextLen - ($nJSONPayloadLen - $PAYLOAD_MAXIMUM_SIZE));
            $payload  = get_payload_message($message_text);
        }
    }
    return  $payload;
}
```

Iphone side i added:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken { 


    NSLog(@"It comes<<<<<<<<<<<<<---------------------------------------");
    NSString *str = [NSString 
                     stringWithFormat:@"Device Token=%@",deviceToken];
    NSLog(str);
    NSString *token = [NSString stringWithFormat:deviceToken];
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setObject:token forKey:@"deviceId"];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err { 
    NSLog(@"It comes with error---------------------------->>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Error: %@", err];
    NSLog(str);    
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [prefs setObject:str forKey:@"deviceId"];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    for (id key in userInfo) {
        NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [userInfo objectForKey:key]);
    }    

}
```

also i use:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


    UIImageView *loading = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460)];
    [loading setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];
    [window addSubview:loading];
    [loading release];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    }
```

This is my whole code that used:

iPhone Log shows while Device is Connected:

```
2012-02-03 19:51:32.872 BiiMe[7544:707] It comes<<<<<<<<<<<<<---------------------------------------
2012-02-03 19:51:32.873 BiiMe[7544:707] Device Token=<26d906c5 c273446d 5f40d2c1 73ddd3f6 869b2666 b1c7afd5 173d69b6 629def70>
```

all times server side:
 Connection Established

What is missing by me..? or what should i implemented in my code:

your answer will help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOption` in AppDelegete

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
     registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
                                         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

Comment: i used it dear... what i do more?

Comment: it is ok... push notification enable

Comment: Please Check Your Deveploment File (http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/programming-apple-push-notification-services)

Comment: I think your Both side Code is right ... Please check your Development Profile

Answer (score 2):

`gateway.push.apple.com` is used for released application or AdHoc application. If you are checking with development profile you might need to change it to `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes coding is right. One more thing how do you send your devicetoken to your server? as I don't see any code for that

Comment: for testing i make a test.php file in that i just call pushToIphone('5094cd6f63b10709ac1f93ec0e251f34699d5cfd','13');

Comment: is this devicetoken generated from application ?

Comment: my didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken() method was not called what should i do>?